# Can you use POST to run a query in Solr (/select)

Tags: c#, .net, solr, httpclient

I have queries that I am running against out solr index that sometimes have very long query parameters, I get errors when i run these queries, which i assume are do to the limit of a GET query parameters.

Here is the method I use to query (JSON), this is to show I am using the Http Extensions (the client i use is a thin wrapper for HttpClient) not an end to end solution.  90% of the queries run fine, it is just when the params are large i get the 500 error from solr.  I have read somewhere you can use POSt's when doing the select command but have not found examples of how to do it.  Any help would be fantastic!

```
    public string GetJson(HttpQueryString qs)
    {
        using (var client = new DAC.US.Web.XmlHttpServiceClient(this.Uri))
        {
            client.Client.DefaultHeaders.Authorization = new Microsoft.Http.Headers.Credential("Basic", DAC.US.Encryption.Hash.WebServiceCredintials);
            qs.Add("wt", "json");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Version))
                qs.Add("version", this.Version);

            using (var response = client.Get(new Uri(@"select/", UriKind.Relative), qs))
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

1. Don't assume. Check the Solr log to confirm the reason of this error.
2. /select accepts POST requests without issues. You can try this with curl:

   ```
   curl -d "q=*:*&rows=1" http://localhost:8983/solr/select
   ```

   I can't comment on XmlHttpServiceClient as it seems to be some proprietary code, but see [this page](http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx) for an example of POSTing using HttpWebRequest.

BTW: there are .net libraries that implement communicating with Solr, no need to roll your own unless you have some very weird requirements.

Comment: I am using not using the HttpWebRequest, technically but am using a thin wrapper for the Microsoft.Http library. I have fairly dodd requirements, which i found more difficult to implement with SolrNet and such. I guess my main question is this, is the POST param data equal to what the querystring looks like for the GET.  From your curl example it seems the post takes 1 param...

Comment: @RyanFetz: yes, the POST data is the same as the querystring.

Comment: @RyanFetz: BTW I'm interested in hearing about those difficulties with SolrNet :-)

Answer (score 7):

Be sure to set **Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** or you will get a status code of 500.

Curl does this by default.

It would not surprise me if your XmlHttpServiceClient was hard-coded/defaulting to use text/xml as the Content type.  HttpWebRequest is more appropriate.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why the post wasn't working for me.  I finally figured it out, then read your response.  That'll teach me to not check the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Solr Supports HTTP GET and HTTP POST.

While doing HTTP POST set the content type correctly. 
You can verify it using Postman or Fiddler.

Correct content type:
 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Without the correct content type you will get the error message as 
:The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!

Simply post the data to the same path (`http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/select`).

Instead of using query string parameters, POST the same data as a JSON body, within a `params` object key like this:

```
{
  "params": {
     "q": "field:value",
     "rows": 10,
     "wt": "json"
  }
}
```

Comment: `coreName` in the URL is the collection name.